# find specific string after certain pattern in a txt file

Tags: java

so i am new to java.please offer some sample codes if possible. 
The situation is i have a html format in a text file. i need to read the file and find the string after a pattern which is 'data-name'. i need to find every string after the "data-name" through the entire text file. i did some research online . i already used html parser to get the html and store it in a text file. i know i might need to use regular expression. so please help me. Thank you guys!

below is my code for getting the html. the result is concatenated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        URL url = new URL("https://twitter.com/search?q=%23JENOSMROOKIESOPENFOLBACK&src=tren");

        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Desktop/htmlsourcecode.txt")); 

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            out.print(line);
        }
        out.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: You should look into regex, indexOf, or split. I'm not sure what you mean by "every string after" because an HTML file could technically be one whole string, and would be considered one.

Comment: yes.every string i mean the entire html. it is true that html is just a long string. i tried something but it only returns the first value after the 'data-name' once it finds the first one, it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
// External resource(s).
BufferedReader in = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
try {

  URL url = new URL(
      "https://twitter.com/search?q=%23JENOSMROOKIESOPENFOLBACK&src=tren");

  // read text returned by server
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      url.openStream()));

  String line;
  // out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
  // "htmlsourcecode.txt"));

  final String DATA_NAME = "data-name=\"";
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    int pos1 = line.indexOf(DATA_NAME); // opening position.
    if (pos1 > -1) { // did we match?
      // Add the length of the string.
      pos1 += DATA_NAME.length();
      // find the closing quote.
      int pos2 = line.indexOf("\"", pos1 + 1);
      if (pos2 > -1) {
        String dataName = line.substring(pos1,
            pos2);
        System.out.println(dataName);
        // out.print(line);
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  // Close external resource(s).
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
  if (out != null) {
    out.close();
  }
}
```